# Is there a way for a 19th century scientist to prove that the octopus doesn't revive?

Tags: neuroscience, zoology, physiology

Say a sophiscated scientist in the 19th century noted that applying soy sauce on a dead octopus leads to movement of the legs, as a result of the voltage differences resulting from the salt in the soy sauce. (For example, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxgcnU9FpAo))

Is there a way for that scientist to prove, using only the methodologies available at that time, that the decapitated octopus doesn't regain the functions that a octopus brain normally has, for even a few seconds, when the soy sauce is applied?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `delude by medicine`.  If you can clarify that, don't hesitate to add it back in, but I don't think it was adding anything to the meaning.  Also, this has nothing to do with `bioinformatics`.

Comment: Unsure if this is suited for this site. It's really a history question.

Comment: @LanceLafontaine - Nope, this question is really about how could a scientist use less advanced techlogy to conduct a experiment to develop advanced result

Comment: Although a proper theory of action potentials was not developed until the beginning of the 20th century, [Galvani's experiments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luigi_Galvani#Galvani_vs._Volta:_animal_electricity_or_heat_electricity.3F) date back to the 18th century...

Comment: @nico - But that might lead some realigous group think the brain function is come from the heart...

Comment: @Victor: Galvani's experiments were done on frog legs, I don't think the heart was present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The scientist could cut a small piece of the octopus's tentacle and perform the experiment again. If the same result is observed, no other organs are involved.